# C++ Simple letter to number encryption

Tags: c++

I am very new and horrible at C++.
I was hoping someone could figure out what this error means, I seriously have no idea what to do, I am NOT asking to have you to try to make it more effiecent, I realize my uneffieceny.

I am trying to convert letters to numbers, I understand this is weak encryption.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::string ptxt = "";
string etxt = "";
cin >> ptxt;
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'a', '1');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'b', '2');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'c', '3');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'd', '4');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'e', '5');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'f', '6');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'g', '7');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'h', '8');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'i', '9');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'j', '10');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'k', '11');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'l', '12');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'm', '13');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'n', '14');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'o', '15');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'p', '16');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'q', '17');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'r', '18');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 's', '19');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 't', '20');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'u', '21');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'v', '22');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'w', '23');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'x', '24');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'y', '25');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'z', '26');
return 0;
}
```

[Build Log (Debug?)](http://pastebin.com/m2X5UzTF)

Comment: You need to look at the warnings.

Comment: Did you bother reading the errors? `'10'` is not a single character.

Comment: That looks soooo weird, WOW!

Comment: @user657267 I'm sorry I don't understand, do you mean because it is a double digit number? I've noticed the error, just don't know what it is trying to tell me.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a character and a string.

Comment: Your algorithm will never work. Trying to "decrypt" `14`, how do you know if it's supposed to represent `ad` or `n`?

Comment: @NeilKirk How do I resolve this, how do I use strings instead of characters?

Comment: I'd really like to know why you further indent each line even though it's not starting a new code block?

Comment: @KenWhite I will work on that later, at the moment I just want to know how to do letter to number conversion

Comment: `std::replace` works on individual characters only. To replace a substring with another substring of arbitrary lengths will be different. My brain is too sleepy to come up with something right now. But you should take a look at @KenWhite 's comment, as converting 1 character to 2 may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning of the build log:

> ```
> main.cpp|25|warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]|
> ```

A character constant is like `'a'` or `'1'`. If we go and look at the code this warning points to we see:

```
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'l', '12');
```

Note that `'12'`: there are two characters inside that character constant. This is warning you about the fact that you have more than one. What exactly a  'multi-character' character constant is and what they're good for doesn't matter, you don't need them and should not be using them.

If you really want text like "hello" to be encoded as "85121215" or "8 5 12 12 15" then you're going to have to rethink how you do the replacement. This is for two reasons: a multi-character character constant like `'12'` will not look like `12` in your output file, and secondly because `std::replace` will not handle replacing a single character like `l` with multiple characters.

For now lets replace all the mult-character character constants you've got with single-character versions:

```
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'a', '1');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'b', '2');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'c', '3');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'd', '4');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'e', '5');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'f', '6');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'g', '7');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'h', '8');
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'i', '9');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'j', 'a');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'k', 'b');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'l', 'c');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'm', 'd');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'n', 'e');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'o', 'f');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'p', 'g');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'q', 'h');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'r', 'i');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 's', 'j');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 't', 'k');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'u', 'l');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'v', 'm');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'w', 'n');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'x', 'o');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'y', 'p');
std::replace(ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'z', 'q');
```

This change addresses all the warnings in the build log, and also happens to fix all the errors as well.

If you're curious what the errors were: they were just a sort of verbose way of telling you that your arguments to `std::replace()` were not correct. Multi-characters happen to have the type `int` instead of `char`, and `std::replace()` does not accept taking an `int` for the last argument when the second to last argument is a `char`.

```
                                            this has type `int`
                                               |
                                               V
std::replace( ptxt.begin(), ptxt.end(), 'l', '12');
                                         ^
                                         |
                                   this has type `char`... mismatch error between `int` and `char`
```

---

- Taking issues one at a time is a good way to avoid being overwhelmed by all of them at once. Just take them one at a time, starting from the beginning. Often fixing one issue reported earlier will make other warnings and errors go away so you never have to bother with them.
- Do not ignore warnings. Even though your programs may compile and work without all the warnings being fixed, it's a bad habit to ignore them. In fact, you should enable more warnings if you can, and pay attention to those too.